# Can't create schema in postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgres-10

I'm trying to create schema with query:

`CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS hdb_catalog`

but following error occurred:

```
2019-09-10 13:47:37.025 UTC [129] ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_namespace_nspname_index"
2019-09-10 13:47:37.025 UTC [129] DETAIL:  Key (nspname)=(hdb_catalog) already exists.
2019-09-10 13:47:37.025 UTC [129] STATEMENT:  
       CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS hdb_catalog
```

How it is possible with `IF NOT EXISTS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like you have catalog corruption.

With some luck, only the index is affected. You can try to repair it using

```
REINDEX pg_catalog.pg_namespace;
```

Like in all cases of corruption, it is commendable to create a new cluster with `initdb` and use `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` to copy the database there. There might be more problems.

Also, try to find out what caused the corruption. Often it is bad hardware.